# PHP printr to Query String

Tags: php, arrays, printf, query-string

I want to make a query string from the string. I found a method `http_build_query()` for making query string but for my string its not working is there any way to making query string from the string which I get from `print_r`

```
$string = 'Array
    (
    [payplan_gold] => 0
    [payplan_status] => 0
    [onegrams_qty] => 1
    [twograms_qty] => 0
    [fivegrams_qty] => 0
    )'
    echo http_build_query($string );
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: not sur to understand what you want if you want to execute the string use the function eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not valid. The correct code would look like this:

```
$string = array(
  'payplan_gold' => 0,
  'payplan_status' => 0,
  'onegrams_qty' => 1,
  'twograms_qty' => 0,
  'fivegrams_qty' => 0,
);
echo http_build_query($string );
```

which will output:

```
payplan_gold=0&payplan_status=0&onegrams_qty=1&twograms_qty=0&fivegrams_qty=0
```

The var you put into `print_r` is already an array.
You only need to put it into the `http_build_query` function.
There is no need to process the ouput of `print_r`